# Show hint data inside bar in DevExpress chart controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have an [ASP.NET web forms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms) application which uses [DevExpress's bar chart controls](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8103). In the below **[side-by-side bar chart](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2972)**:

[image: need hint data inside bar]

I needed to show some extra information apart from *traditional* **x** and **y** argument-values using [series point's](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfChartsSeries_ToolTipHintDataMembertopic) [{HINT} pattern](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfChartsSeries_ToolTipPointPatterntopic) (`Hospital Admissions: 130, (65%)`) - as per the image.

Now, I need to show it in the bar itself. Like the control shows `by-default` for [**Stacked bar charts**](http://demos.devexpress.com/xtrachartsdemos/BarViewTypes/BarStackedSeries.aspx):

[image: stacked bar chart]

> How do I push the Tool tip hint data to be shown inside the data bars?

Any suggestions, kind folks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to access the current data row directly when handling the [`CustomDrawSeriesPoint`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressXtraChartsWebWebChartControl_CustomDrawSeriesPointtopic) event. Cast the `e.SeriesPoint`.

Tag property to the corresponding type (e.g., `DataRowView`). This should make it possible to update the `SeriesPoint` label text.

You can find a small sample project that illustrates this approach in the [Chart Series Label from a dataset column that is not part of the series](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/T208995.aspx) ticket.